# Windows Authentication Timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, windows-authentication

How can you suspend access to a user session after a specified interval of inactivity when using Windows Integrated Security for an ASP.NET MVC Website?

Answer (score 1):

When using Kerberos for authentication Internet Explorer (IE) will continue sending the same credentials for each subsequent request to the server until one of two things happens:

a)    The user closes their browser.
   b)    The server refuses the credentials with a 401 status code.

This behavior is [KB 264921](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264921).

If we want to simulate a session than we have to implement the following steps:

1. Create a sliding expiration cookie for the duration of the session.
2. Check for that cookie for every request: begin_request or global filters. If the cookie is missing return a 401 status code for that specific request.
3. Next request will trigger the authentication prompt.

I was hoping someone else having a better ideea, this one feels kind of hacky.